# Macro to Group Rows Throughout Excel Document

Tags: excel, macos, grouping

I have looked around and I feel like I am going crazy for not understanding how to do this, or what to do. It seems simple and yet I cannot figure out the best method.

I have an excel document that has 8 rows of data and that is supported by individual data from individuals that is 16 rows long. In total, there are 600 individuals in the dataset.

I was trying to locate a macro that would simply allow me to group every 16 rows in my excel sheet together. Whatever I have tried though, has not worked.

I am using Microsoft Excel 20116 for mac.

Comment: How do you mean "group them together"?

Comment: Through the grouping function in excel. I would like to create groups of the data. I have been able to do a macro to group individual rows within a document in the past, but I cannot seem to get it for the larger range.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("1:16").Select
Selection.Rows.Group

Range("17:32").Select
Selection.Rows.Group
```

Repeat!

If there is a predictable data pattern (i.e. always exactly 16 rows) you might wish to put this inside a loop, where `Range.Select` is offset a further 16 rows each time.

For example:

```
i = 1
j = 16

While i < "YOUR UPPER LIMIT"
  Range(i & ":" & j).Select
  Selection.Rows.Group
  i = i+16
  j = j+16
Next
```

Note that if you group contiguous rows without a break, your groupings will automatically combine. You will need to play around with the line `Range(i & ":" & j).Select` to either use i+1 or j-1 depending on what you want as your display row on the grouping.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Option 1 is what I had originally looked at, but being that I have a about 10,000 rows of data that could take a while.. Option 2 is more of what I was interested in, but I am getting a compile error for some reason?

Comment: Might be slightly different in MacOS, this code works in Excel 2013 for Windows.  Whats the exact error text?